# Broadcast receiver not triggering

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Why my broadcast receiver is only sending and creating notifications? I am trying to make it to switch on a device automatically but the device state is not changing for some reason.

It works if triggered in other classes but not in the broadcast.

please help me find the solution :)

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public boolean isFirstRun = false;  //Set this to true when user initially saves location
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    WemoActivity wemo = new WemoActivity();
    private WeMoSDKContext mWeMoSDKContext = null;
    private String DeviceName = "uuid:Socket-1_0-221412K1100F3A";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
        SharedPreferences mprefs = context.getSharedPreferences("First time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isFirstRun = mprefs.getBoolean("First time", false);

        if (entering) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"in the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Entering");
        } else {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exiting");
            Toast.makeText(context,"out of the region" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        sendNotification(context);
        // automatically switch device state when enter/leave region
        DeviceState(context.getApplicationContext(), entering);

    }

    public void sendNotification(Context context) {
        // String extra=arg1.getExtras().getString("alert").toString();
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String message = "You are near your office/home.";

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,message, when);
        String title = "Proximity Alert!"; 
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
        notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1500;
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        return;
    }

    private void DeviceState(Context context, boolean ON) {
        mWeMoSDKContext = new WeMoSDKContext(context);
        mWeMoSDKContext.addNotificationListener(null);
        if(ON) {
            mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_ON, DeviceName);
        } else {
            mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_OFF, DeviceName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello can u pls post broadcast declaration of manifest ?

Comment: use context instead of context.getApplicationContext(). and try printing something in DeviceState().

Comment: I tried using context but not nothing has changed. print something ?

Comment: @Harry I have added the printing and it prints out when it is triggered. does that mean that the problem is with the device or something ? maybe with        mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_ON, DeviceName); but it works fine in any other class tho. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had you mentioned your receiver in manifest file like this :

```
 <receiver
            android:name="receiver_name"
            android:enabled="true" >
```

Comment: Yes i did . (Without enabled=true). Tho i used filter so its not needed in manifest i assume... The notification is created, but the device state is not triggered